# How can I disable Escape key binding in Zoom

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, zoom-meeting

How can I disable Escape key binding in Zoom?

When I press it, it shows the meeting controls while I am sharing my screen. I use escape a lot in coding and it is annoying that I have to re-hide the meeting controls every time I hit Escape.

Comment: I took the liberty and created a discussion on the official zoom forums using almost exactly your wording. I hope you don't mind. :)
https://community.zoom.com/t5/Meetings/How-can-I-disable-Escape-key-binding-in-Zoom/m-p/22247#M10721

Comment: that's really annoying oO